# iOS xcode, Web services, NSURLConnection second call fails

Tags: ios, xcode, service, web

iPad development, iOS 4.3, objective-c, xcode 4.1.

I have created a wrapper class, which is used to call a method on a web service. It works fine when I make the first call, but fails on subsequent calls.

A method in my class, "runMethod::", opens a NSURLConnection and does the call asynchronously, with the wrapper class itself as the NSURLConnection delegate.

I have read somewhere that there's a fault with Android, which keeps a pool of connections. When you try to make a connection a second time it fails because the previous connection has been kept open, despite the code closing it. Hence, I suspect the problem is that the connection remains in the pool, and when I try to make another one it clashes? Maybe xcode has a similar issue?

And the symptoms of the failure are a seemingly random 'bad access' on a random line in one of the delegate selectors, which suggests this has something to do with threading - I understand that HTTP connections operate on their own thread.

I can provide the full wrapper class if need be, but anyone any ideas?

Comment: Is your wrapper a singleton class? Do you create a NSURLConnection dor each request? Maybe some code would help yes :)

Comment: Sorry, I spent ages copying the lengthy wrapper class into the article yesterday, then it all got lost when I posted.

Comment: ... and to answer your other point, I'm not sure what a singleton class is. Yes, I create a NSURLConnection each call, and upon the async response I close it.

Comment: (I keep hitting Return to start a new line, and the goddam comment gets posted unintentionally) ...

The creation of the NSURLConnection triggers the async call, which is why I recreate the connection each time. Perhaps I should create a class variable, and check whether it has been instantiated? If it has, I could run some method against it to submit another call?

Comment: Did you mean iOS4.3 and Xcode4? Cause I believe you got it reversed.

Comment: Why bring Android into the question? iOS and Android are entirely separate operating systems; it's not likely that a bug in one would also be present in the other. Also: Xcode is an IDE, iOS is the operating system; Xcode then has nothing to do with any problems related to your connection.

Answer (score 0):

A 'bad access' error simply indicates that you're dereferencing an invalid pointer. This is most often due to improper memory management, such as failing to retain some object. Code would help, but first try the Analyze command in Xcode -- the static analyzer is pretty good at finding memory problems.